# WPF Button behavior using Triggers

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, controltemplate

I have a `Button` with custom appearance defined by a `ControlTemplate`.

It contains a `Canvas` which contains a `Path`. I would like to add changes in `Path.Opacity` depending on mouse state:

- default - 0.5
- mouse over, not pressed - 1.0
- mouse over, pressed - 0.5

The first cases are covered simply by setting local value of `Path.Opacity` to `0.5` and adding one `Trigger` for `IsMouseOver`:

```
<Button x:Class="ImagingShop.Panosphere.Controls.PathButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
        Name="pathButton">

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                <Canvas.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                        <Setter Property="Path.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Path.Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Canvas.Style>
                <Path Data="{Binding ElementName=pathButton, Path=PathData}" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Button>
```

However, the third case does not work. I have added the following trigger:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Path.Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

So this should set `Path.Opacity` to `0.75` is mouse hovers over the button **AND** the button is pressed.

I am stuck with this as the opacity is changed to `0.5` instead of `0.75`! The trigger seems to apply, but does not work as expected...

Comment: So - it is not possible to restyle button using XAML only? It seems that Button.IsPressed should work - there is an [XAML example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx) doing just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you just not using the `Opacity` of the `Button` and have Triggers on the `Button`'s `Style` directly, Your `ControlTemplate` does not have anything but this `Path` anyways.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PathButton}">
  <Setter Property="Opacity"
          Value=".5" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PathButton}">
        <Canvas Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Background="Transparent">
          <Path Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Data="{Binding ElementName=pathButton,
                                Path=PathData}"
                Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}"
                Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Canvas>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
              Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Opacity"
              Value="1" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
              Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Opacity"
              Value=".75" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

will produce the output your expecting.

**Update:**

You can just have the `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` and have the Subclass declaration in a code-behind file. This will produce only one xaml file. You are not left with 2 xaml files in this method.

Have also switched the binding for `PathData` to a `RelativeSource` binding.

You can download a sample of this from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3trlv89r1kxixj4/WpfApplication1.rar). Open it and check it out

I've also used an add-in [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45) that lets you group files into custom groups by editing the vsproj file and adding a `DependsOn` attribute. That lets you group your `ResourceDictionary` and Code-behind Class file into one Entity `PathButton.xaml` just like how `UserControl` and `Window` look in the IDE with their code-behind file.

Comment: OK this partially works, but I had to move entire style outside PathButton.xaml code - the reasons I wanted to have it inside are that the `{TemplateBinding PathData}` does not work, only `{Binding ElementName=pathButton, Path=PathData}` does. PathData is a normal dependency property of type String. The style now refers to some element name which is a magic constant and I would like to have the code as self-contained as possible (single XAML file would be best...). If every custom control have at least two XAML files (one for code and one for style), the code would be quite scattered...

Comment: @Libor I've updated my answer with a small description and link to a dropbox download that you can get and have a look to see how you can structure this in just 1 xaml file and also using a RelativeSource binding instead of TemplateBinding for PathData. Download it and have a look for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works like a charm. I tried at first to add the PathButton style inside Button.Style but this caused type mismatch since the style targets PathButton and not a Button. Thanks to your code I realized I need no XAML for the button except the style itself. I am still confused about the TemplateBindingExtension, since it works with WPF control properties seamlessly, but does not work at all with custom control properties... Well, at least there is a solution (though it does not look as simple and elegant as TemplateBinding).

Comment: @Libor Yh it's a known issue that TemplateBinding does not work on Custom DP's at times. You can find some threads talking abt it here on SO. You could use `{Binding PathData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` which is slightly shorter :) since this is just within a Style